# How to concat values in case statement?

Tags: sql, oracle

DDL for table:

```
  CREATE TABLE "AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION" 
   (    "USER_ID" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "USER_NAME" VARCHAR2(200 BYTE), 
    "MAIL" VARCHAR2(400 BYTE), 
    "FULLNAME" VARCHAR2(200 BYTE), 
    "GENDER" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE), 
    "USER_DAY" VARCHAR2(10 BYTE), 
    "USER_MONTH" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE), 
    "USER_YEAR" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE), 
    "CREATED" NUMBER(38,0), 
    "STATUS" VARCHAR2(10 BYTE), 
    "UU_ID" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "MOBILE" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    "CHANGED" NUMBER(38,0)
   );
```

Insert Statements:

```
Insert into AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION (USER_ID,USER_NAME,MAIL,FULLNAME,GENDER,USER_DAY,USER_MONTH,USER_YEAR,CREATED,STATUS,UU_ID,MOBILE,CHANGED) values (914981,'srik1977@gmail.com','srikes1977@gmail.com','Birendra Mohan',null,'05','March','1977',1412433302,'1','69945218-cc7f-46f5','9471067',null);
Insert into AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION (USER_ID,USER_NAME,MAIL,FULLNAME,GENDER,USER_DAY,USER_MONTH,USER_YEAR,CREATED,STATUS,UU_ID,MOBILE,CHANGED) values (916653,'mah@gmail.com','mahe@gmail.com','MAHESH DEOCHAKE','male','18','July','1989',1412439002,'1','4563adc0-345b-4779-a8ee','7709910',null);
Insert into AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION (USER_ID,USER_NAME,MAIL,FULLNAME,GENDER,USER_DAY,USER_MONTH,USER_YEAR,CREATED,STATUS,UU_ID,MOBILE,CHANGED) values (916665,'hars@hotmail.com','haveri@hotmail.com','Harshal Jhaveri',null,'08','May','1992',1412439002,'1','a10a3f0c-5892-4579-aef6-46a','8568013',null);
Insert into AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION (USER_ID,USER_NAME,MAIL,FULLNAME,GENDER,USER_DAY,USER_MONTH,USER_YEAR,CREATED,STATUS,UU_ID,MOBILE,CHANGED) values (890991,'gu1952@gmail.com','gunran1952@gmail.com','subramani gunasekaran','male','17','October','1950',1412358602,'1','6b4c7077-8864-4702-','44697999',null);
Insert into AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION (USER_ID,USER_NAME,MAIL,FULLNAME,GENDER,USER_DAY,USER_MONTH,USER_YEAR,CREATED,STATUS,UU_ID,MOBILE,CHANGED) values (891053,'amini@gmail.com','amihani@gmail.com','AMIR RANJAN DHANI','male','20','August','1992',1412358602,'1','62dd0cb4-c86b-4634-ba6','9432880',null);
Insert into AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION (USER_ID,USER_NAME,MAIL,FULLNAME,GENDER,USER_DAY,USER_MONTH,USER_YEAR,CREATED,STATUS,UU_ID,MOBILE,CHANGED) values (891055,'pringhc0@gmail.com','pravghc0@gmail.com','Praveen Singh Chouhan','male','10','April','1990',1412358602,'1','037f1079-db85-49d7','04663542',null);
Insert into AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION (USER_ID,USER_NAME,MAIL,FULLNAME,GENDER,USER_DAY,USER_MONTH,USER_YEAR,CREATED,STATUS,UU_ID,MOBILE,CHANGED) values (892719,'badkt@yahoo.com','bammadkt@yahoo.com','Muhammed Basheer','male','05','July','1994',1412362502,'1','10c07ce7-badf-4204-b2a9','7232903',null);
Insert into AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION (USER_ID,USER_NAME,MAIL,FULLNAME,GENDER,USER_DAY,USER_MONTH,USER_YEAR,CREATED,STATUS,UU_ID,MOBILE,CHANGED) values (892729,'swaar@gmail.com','swnwar@gmail.com','swapnil papinwar','male','08','September','1986',1412362502,'1','2f8940ef-3136-425','9818122',null);
Insert into AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION (USER_ID,USER_NAME,MAIL,FULLNAME,GENDER,USER_DAY,USER_MONTH,USER_YEAR,CREATED,STATUS,UU_ID,MOBILE,CHANGED) values (896209,'raj@yahoo.com','rajan@yahoo.com','Rajiv Nayan','male','10','June','1969',1412388301,'1','8008f636-916b-4982-baad-','9810769',null);
Insert into AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION (USER_ID,USER_NAME,MAIL,FULLNAME,GENDER,USER_DAY,USER_MONTH,USER_YEAR,CREATED,STATUS,UU_ID,MOBILE,CHANGED) values (465,'Jaysparikh','jay@gmail.com','Jay Parikh','male','31','January','1984',1406359580,'1','c04b7129-b04e-4ca5-9199-','9586817',null);
Insert into AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION (USER_ID,USER_NAME,MAIL,FULLNAME,GENDER,USER_DAY,USER_MONTH,USER_YEAR,CREATED,STATUS,UU_ID,MOBILE,CHANGED) values (476,'sknyer','sknr@gmail.com','Sasidharan Nair','male','26','October','1968',1406359591,'1','69288f05-bfbb-4f5e-9561-71e','530154',null);
Insert into AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION (USER_ID,USER_NAME,MAIL,FULLNAME,GENDER,USER_DAY,USER_MONTH,USER_YEAR,CREATED,STATUS,UU_ID,MOBILE,CHANGED) values (504,'casstifer','sir@gmail.com','Aditya Verma','male','25','December','1995',1406359633,'1','a4e8ad7b-a5f8-476b-a779-','742842',null);
```

Query:

```
SELECT
    user_id as user_id,
    user_name as user_name,
    mail as user_mail,
    fullname as full_name,
    case when (gender='male' or gender='mail' or gender='Male') then 'Male'
    when (gender='female' or gender='Female') then 'Female' else 'Others'
    end as gender,
    case
    when user_month='January' then '1'
    when user_month='February' then '2'
    when user_month='March' then '3'
    when user_month='April' then '4'
    when user_month='May' then '5'
    when user_month='June' then '6'
    when user_month='July' then '7'
    when user_month='August' then '8'
    when user_month='September' then '9'
    when user_month='Ocotober' then '10'
    when user_month='November' then '11'
    when user_month='December' then '12' 
    end user_month,
    case 
    when (user_day is not null or user_day<>'') and (user_month is not null or user_month<>'')   and (user_year is not null or user_year<>'') 
    then  user_day ||'-' || user_month ||'-' || user_year else '' end as dob,
    created,
    status as status,
    uu_id as uuid,
    mobile as mobile,
    changed 
FROM
    auth_user_registration;
```

I need to concat the `user_day`, `user_month` and `user_year` into single column like this (01-01-2022) format current format is (01-January-2022).
Please help me to do this.

Comment: Why are you storing day, month and year as separate columns, and as strings? Anyway... you already have a case expression that converts the month name to a number (!), so just put that inside the concatenation. Or, concatenate the strings, then use `to_date()` with error handling, and `to_char()` back to the format you want... (Your `<>''` comparisons aren't doing anything by the way - those will always evaluate to unknown, which is effectively false.)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I'd say that you're doing it wrong. You should store dates as dates (into a `DATE` datatype column), not separate days/months/years into their own columns, with no control over it. What if you entered 'Janiary'? That's obviously *January*, but - to recognize it as such - you'd have to put (a lot?) of effort into it. Or, why wouldn't day be 84? 84-Janiary-2022; doesn't look OK.

Anyway:

- first concatenate those values
- apply `to_date` function to the result, with appropriate format model
- then apply `to_char` to that `DATE` datatype value, using target format model

---

```
SQL> SELECT user_day,
  2         user_month,
  3         user_year,
  4         TO_CHAR (
  5            TO_DATE (
  6               user_day || '-' || user_month || '-' || user_year
  7                  DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR,
  8               'dd-month-yyyy',
  9               'nls_date_language=english'),
 10            'dd-mm-yyyy') AS dob
 11    FROM auth_user_registration;

USER_DAY   USER_MONTH      USER_YEAR       DOB
---------- --------------- --------------- ----------
05         March           1977            05-03-1977

SQL>
```

---

I'd rather suggest the following approach:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE auth_user_registration
  2  (
  3     user_id     NUMBER (*, 0),
  4     user_name   VARCHAR2 (200 BYTE),
  5     dob         DATE                       --> DATE datatype
  6  );

Table created.

SQL> INSERT INTO auth_user_registration (user_id, user_name, dob)
  2       VALUES (914981, 'srik1977@gmail.com', DATE '1977-03-05');

1 row created.

SQL> SELECT dob, TO_CHAR (dob, 'dd-mm-yyyy') result FROM auth_user_registration;

DOB      RESULT
-------- ----------
05.03.77 05-03-1977

SQL>
```

---

P.S. Consider NOT to use double quotes while working with Oracle; they bring problems.

Comment: Given the potential for garbage values, or just nulls as those seem to be expected, this seems a good time to use `default null on conversion error` in the `to_date()` call...

Comment: @AlexPoole creating table and storing values in table is not at my end, i can only fetch values from created table, as dob,  day, month and year are storing in three table

Answer (score 1):

You already have a case expression to convert month names to numbers, but you seem to be expecting the reference to `user_month` in your concatenation to use the result of that case, because you aliased it with the same name. That won't work; you can't user a column alias in the same level of query it is defined (except in an order-by clause), so that is still referring to the original table column with the same name - hence you seeing the month names.

You need to move the case expression inside the concatenation. But you've also spelled 'October' wrong, and from your example you want zero-padded month numbers; and a simple case expression would be a bit less typing than a searched one here. So you could do:

```
SELECT
    user_id as user_id,
    user_name as user_name,
    mail as user_mail,
    fullname as full_name,
    case when (gender='male' or gender='mail' or gender='Male') then 'Male'
    when (gender='female' or gender='Female') then 'Female' else 'Others'
    end as gender,
    case 
    when user_day is not null and user_month is not null and user_year is not null
    then user_day ||'-'
      || case user_month
        when 'January' then '01'
        when 'February' then '02'
        when 'March' then '03'
        when 'April' then '04'
        when 'May' then '05'
        when 'June' then '06'
        when 'July' then '07'
        when 'August' then '08'
        when 'September' then '09'
        when 'October' then '10'
        when 'November' then '11'
        when 'December' then '12' 
      end
      ||'-' || user_year end as dob,
    created,
    status as status,
    uu_id as uuid,
    mobile as mobile,
    changed 
FROM
    auth_user_registration;
```

| USER_ID | USER_NAME | USER_MAIL | FULL_NAME | GENDER | DOB | CREATED | STATUS | UUID | MOBILE | CHANGED |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 914981 | srik1977@gmail.com | srikes1977@gmail.com | Birendra Mohan | Others | 05-03-1977 | 1412433302 | 1 | 69945218-cc7f-46f5 | 9471067 | *null* |
| 916653 | mah@gmail.com | mahe@gmail.com | MAHESH DEOCHAKE | Male | 18-07-1989 | 1412439002 | 1 | 4563adc0-345b-4779-a8ee | 7709910 | *null* |
| 916665 | hars@hotmail.com | haveri@hotmail.com | Harshal Jhaveri | Others | 08-05-1992 | 1412439002 | 1 | a10a3f0c-5892-4579-aef6-46a | 8568013 | *null* |
| 890991 | gu1952@gmail.com | gunran1952@gmail.com | subramani gunasekaran | Male | 17-10-1950 | 1412358602 | 1 | 6b4c7077-8864-4702- | 44697999 | *null* |
| 891053 | amini@gmail.com | amihani@gmail.com | AMIR RANJAN DHANI | Male | 20-08-1992 | 1412358602 | 1 | 62dd0cb4-c86b-4634-ba6 | 9432880 | *null* |
| 891055 | pringhc0@gmail.com | pravghc0@gmail.com | Praveen Singh Chouhan | Male | 10-04-1990 | 1412358602 | 1 | 037f1079-db85-49d7 | 04663542 | *null* |
| 892719 | badkt@yahoo.com | bammadkt@yahoo.com | Muhammed Basheer | Male | 05-07-1994 | 1412362502 | 1 | 10c07ce7-badf-4204-b2a9 | 7232903 | *null* |
| 892729 | swaar@gmail.com | swnwar@gmail.com | swapnil papinwar | Male | 08-09-1986 | 1412362502 | 1 | 2f8940ef-3136-425 | 9818122 | *null* |
| 896209 | raj@yahoo.com | rajan@yahoo.com | Rajiv Nayan | Male | 10-06-1969 | 1412388301 | 1 | 8008f636-916b-4982-baad- | 9810769 | *null* |
| 465 | Jaysparikh | jay@gmail.com | Jay Parikh | Male | 31-01-1984 | 1406359580 | 1 | c04b7129-b04e-4ca5-9199- | 9586817 | *null* |
| 476 | sknyer | sknr@gmail.com | Sasidharan Nair | Male | 26-10-1968 | 1406359591 | 1 | 69288f05-bfbb-4f5e-9561-71e | 530154 | *null* |
| 504 | casstifer | sir@gmail.com | Aditya Verma | Male | 25-12-1995 | 1406359633 | 1 | a4e8ad7b-a5f8-476b-a779- | 742842 | *null* |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ZTWqT7ew?hide=131056)

Note though that if you have a month name that isn't in the list, or is spelled wrong, or is in a different (typographic) case (e.g. all lowercase, 'january'), then the case expression will evaluate to null so you could end up with something like `84--2022` to borrow Littlefoot's example.

But it would be simpler to convert to and from a date as Littlefoot has shown, or to follow normal practice and just store a single date value instead of three separate string values, for all the reasons already given.